Null Value in my Address Type and Contact Type upon clicking submit button using ASP.NET Core
can some help me with my error. I trying to save the resident information, for resident,address and contact information, Now I am encountering a null value for address type and contact type.
In this scenario, I have multi forms then this page is the final page (Verification of details of resident) if the details was correct.
The purpose of this as i said for verification.
As you can see the address type and contact type is disable it because this is not editable this already filled up in the past forms.
This the code for Contact and Address
 public IActionResult RegisterFinal()
 {
     // Retrieve residentFromStorage, ensuring it's never null
     string residentJson = TempData["Resident"].ToString();
     Resident residentDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Resident>(residentJson);
     string addressJson = TempData["Address"].ToString();
     List<Address> addressDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Address>>(addressJson);
     string contactJson = TempData["Contact"].ToString();
     List<Contact> contactDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Contact>>(contactJson);

    

     // Now, create the finalRegistrationModel with the retrieved data
     var finalRegistrationModel = new Registration
     {
         Resident = residentDetails,
         Addresses = addressDetails ?? new List<Address>(), // Use?? to ensure Addresses is never null
         Contacts = contactDetails ?? new List<Contact>() // Use?? to ensure Contacts is never null
     };

     return View(finalRegistrationModel);
 }

RegisterFinal.cshtml
 <!-- Display Address Information -->
 @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Addresses.Count; i++)
 {
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
             <label class="form-label">Address type</label>
             <select asp-for="Addresses[i].AddressType" asp-items="@(new SelectList(new List<SelectListItem>
         {
             new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "Permanent" },
             new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "Present" }
         }, "Value", "Text", Model.Addresses[i].AddressType))" class="form-select" disabled>
             </select>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group col-md-3 mb-3">
             <label for="houseno">House No:</label>
             <input asp-for="Addresses[i].HouseNumber" id="houseno"  class="form-control" readonly>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group col-md-3 mb-3">
             <label for="street">Street:</label>
             <input asp-for="Addresses[i].Street" id="street"  class="form-control" readonly>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group col-md-3 mb-3">
             <label for="barangay">Barangay:</label>
             <input asp-for="Addresses[i].Barangay" id="barangay" class="form-control" readonly>
         </div>
     </div>
 }
 <!-- Display Contact Information -->
 @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Contacts.Count; i++)
 {
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
             <label class="form-label">Contact type</label>
             <select asp-for="Contacts[i].ContactType" asp-items="@(new SelectList(new List<SelectListItem>
         {
             new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "Mobile Number" },
             new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "Home Number" }
         }, "Value", "Text", Model.Contacts[i].ContactType))" class="form-select" disabled>
             </select>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
             <label for="contactNumber">Contact Number:</label>
             <input asp-for="Contacts[i].ContactNumber" id="contactNumber" class="form-control" readonly>
         </div>
     </div>




Can you share what is the ContactType type?

@YongShun the data type is string

The <select> with disabled attribute will not be able to send the value.
You should work with the <input type="hidden"> to send the value.
<select asp-for="Contacts[i].ContactType" asp-items="@(new SelectList(new List<SelectListItem>
   {
       new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "Mobile Number" },
       new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "Home Number" }
   }, "Value", "Text", Model.Contacts[i].ContactType))" class="form-select" disabled>
</select>

<input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Contacts[i].ContactType)" />

